# Designing Function to Reduce Return Variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, struct, output, cell

This is NOT a question where I need to know how to add A+B in `MATLAB`.  This is more of a *code design question*.

I have few function files that return a numeric matrix and index info on the matrix.  For example

```
function [Mat1, IdxID, IdxDate, IdxVal, IdxMarker, IdxOpen, ...] = First () 
    .... 
    .... % where IdxId = 1 ; IdxDate = 2 ; ...
end 


function [Mat1, IdxUid, IdxName, IdxVal, Mat2, IdxUid2, IdxSalary2, ...] = Second () 
    ....
    .... % where IdxUid= 1 ; IdxName= 2 ; ...
end
```

As you can see the code becomes clunky and when I call these functions, I have to declare an equal number of outputs to catch all the indices.  The advantage is if I suddenly swap ID & Date columns, the calling functions do not change as I simply make ID=2, Date=1.  I also have the advantage of renaming these variables inside the function.

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm testing whether `struct` or `cell` can be used for indices.  I can't use `datasets` or `cell` for returning numeric matrix.  Too much time is lost in translating it into numbers.  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you are actually doing with each variable. My method will work, but the detailed design will depend on the hierarchy, types, and what you will do with the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can return arrays/cells/structs instead. For instance, `id` can be a struct with multiple variables. Your function definition could be as follows.

```
function [Mat, Id] = Second () 
    ...
end
```

In your function, have the following set:

```
Id.Name
Id.Val
Id.Salary
...
```

If you find that you have multiple structs with the same exact structure, you can even consider `objects`.

Please clarify with more details on the structure if you want a more detailed answer.